# Using Select Library in react but in generating pdf it does not show its items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu, pdf-generation, html2canvas

I use the "Select" library in my React code. (import Select from 'react-select'). I want to make the pdf from this page and use html2canvas to do that. But it does not show the select item in pdf.

```
<div className="row mb-1 mt-3">
      <Select
        isDisabled
        isMulti
        value={inspection?.inspectionEquiptmentOptions?.map((option: 
       IInspectionEquiptmentOption) =>
        ({
          value: option.id,
          label: option.name,
        }))}
      /> 
    </div>
```

and my pdf generating function is like below:

```
    const downloadPDF = () => {
setCreatingPDF(true);
setImgCount(0);
pdf = new jsPDF("p", "px", "a4");
pdf.html(document.getElementById("formDetails") as HTMLElement, {
  html2canvas: {
    scale: 0.33,
  },
  margin: [25, 0, 25, 0],
  x: 0.5,
  y: 0.5,
  callback: function (pdf) {
    pdf.save(`Inspection Date: ${FormatDateOptions(new Date(inspection?.inspectionDate!), DateFormatOptions.enAU, FormatType.ddmmyyyy)}`);
  },
});
if (components.length + actions.length > 9) {
  pdf.addPage();
}
if (components.length + actions.length > 9 + 49) {
  pdf.addPage();
}
if (components.length + actions.length > 9 + 49 + 49) {
  pdf.addPage();
}
const pages = pdf.getNumberOfPages();
if (imagesData.length > 0) {
  AddImages(imagesData, pages);
}

const pageWidth = pdf.internal.pageSize.width;
const pageHeight = pdf.internal.pageSize.height;

for (let p = 0; p < pages; p++) {
  let horizontalPos = pageWidth / 2;
  let verticalPos = pageHeight - 10;
  pdf.setFontSize(10);
  pdf.setPage(p + 1);
  pdf.text(`Page ${p + 1} of ${pages + imagesData.length}`, horizontalPos, verticalPos, {
    align: "center", //Optional text styling});
  });
  pdf.addImage(LOGO, "JPEG", pageWidth - 50, pageHeight - 20, 30, 11);
}
```

};

what is the problem with my code?